# How to improve the readability of a for-like function taking multiple parameters?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, readability

I made this function:

```
-- Generates multiple random values
randoms :: (Random a) => StdGen -> Int -> a -> a -> ([a], StdGen)
randoms rndGen nbrsCount min max = randomNbrs' nbrsCount min max ([], rndGen) where
    randomNbrs' rndGen 0 min max cumul = cumul
    randomNbrs' rndGen count min max cumul = randomNbrs' rndGen (count-1) min max (values, snd rndGen') where
        rndGen' = randomR (min, max) rndGen
        values = fst rndGen' : values
```

and its hard to read. I can't find how to improve its readability though since I'm new to Haskell. How can this be made easier to read and more concise?

Comment: What are `min` and `max` used for here?

Comment: the minimum and maximum value that can be generated by the StdGen. I just realized that I am missing some codes though, and the function isn't working at all. I'll edit right now.

Comment: Looks a bit like it might be `genRandoms :: Random a => StdGen -> Int -> a -> a -> ([a], StdGen) = genRandoms g n min max = let (gi, go) = split g in (take n (randomRs (min, max) gi), go)`

Comment: `randoms` is already a name in `System.Random` which is why I changed the name, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there are a few simple things you can do off the bat. First, you can use pattern matching to decompose your tuples without multiple expressions. You also don't need to pass around an instance of your random generator, since you already have it in your tuple, again pattern matching will let you access it.

```
randoml :: (Random a, RandomGen b)=> b -> Int -> a -> a -> ([a], b)
randoml rndGen nbrsCount minVal maxVal = randomNbrs' nbrsCount ([], rndGen)
  where
    randomNbrs' 0 cumul = cumul
    randomNbrs' count (values, gen) = randomNbrs' (count-1) (newVal:values, newGen)
      where
        (newVal, newGen) = randomR (minVal, maxVal) gen
```

I renamed some of your variables as they conflict with other names in either `Prelude` or `System.Random`.

Now this is already looking a lot cleaner. The next step you could go for would be adding a `foldr` instead of your explicit recursion. It is sort of idiomatic Haskell. If you haven't used a fold yet, don't worry you will get to it soon. A fold is really just a way to express a common form of recursion where you operate over a collection of items, accumulating the final result as you go.

```
randoml :: (Random a, RandomGen b)=> b -> Int -> a -> a -> ([a], b)
randoml rndGen nbrsCount minVal maxVal = foldr (\ _ (vals, gen) ->
                                                 let
                                                   (val, newGen) = randomR (minVal, maxVal) gen
                                                 in
                                                  (val:vals, newGen))
                                          ([], rndGen) [0..nbrsCount-1]
```

Or if you prefer without the lambda expression

```
randoml :: (Random a, RandomGen b)=> b -> Int -> a -> a -> ([a], b)
randoml rndGen nbrsCount minVal maxVal = foldr func ([], rndGen) [0..nbrsCount-1]
  where
    func _ (vals, gen) = (val:vals, newGen)
      where
        (val, newGen) = randomR (minVal, maxVal) gen
```

Comment: I think your `foldr` has an off-by-one error. You might also use `iterate ... !! nbrsCount`.

Comment: So much cleaner. Thank you!

Comment: I was going to say you should merge the two `where` clauses into one, which would be more idiomatic, but your way is actually cleaner because it makes it clear that `val` and `newGen` are only used in `func`. On the other hand, you might consider renaming `func` to `go` to match common usage.

Comment: @dfeuer I go back and forth on how I feel about more than one `where` clause. Part of me hates having more than one, but the OOP part of me says it is good because it further isolates the variables to only the scope in which they should be accessed.

Comment: Isolating things isn't just OOPish! Haskellers go so far as to write point-free code and eta-reduce expressions to make it clear what their code *doesn't* do. I think the `where`-merging is likely a visual thing.

Comment: @dfeuer The `where`s cannot be trivially merged; the inner one uses a function parameter (`gen`) of the outer one.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, I missed that!

Answer (score 7):

I really like to use [`MonadRandom`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.2.0.1) in these situations:

```
import Control.Monad.Random

randomsR :: (Random a, RandomGen b) => b -> Int -> a -> a -> ([a], b)
randomsR gen nb min max = flip runRand gen        -- run the random monad
                          . sequence              -- get the random monad out of the list
                          . replicate nb          -- generate nb values
                          $ getRandomR (min, max) -- the generator for one value
```

You can also shorten it (thanks  Ørjan):

```
randomsR :: (Random a, RandomGen b) => b -> Int -> a -> a -> ([a], b)
randomsR gen nb min max = flip runRand gen
                          . replicateM nb
                          $ getRandomR (min, max)
```

or

```
randomsR :: (Random a, RandomGen b) => b -> Int -> a -> a -> ([a], b)
randomsR gen nb min max = flip runRand gen
                          . fmap (take nb)
                          $ getRandomRs (min, max)
```

Comment: `sequence . replicate nb = replicateM nb`.